# fill a dataframe of 0 and 1 series with the first values of another dataframe pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a df containing prices:

```
close
                  SPY         F      AAPL
Date                                     
1995-01-03  31.205567  5.503672  1.247298
1995-01-04  31.354707  5.651756  1.279801
1995-01-05  31.354707  5.602394  1.263550
1995-01-06  31.386606  5.602394  1.365121
1995-01-09  31.418575  5.701112  1.339220
1995-01-10  31.450542  5.602394  1.419970
1995-01-11  31.471809  5.602394  1.519510
1995-01-12  31.482511  5.553033  1.474819
```

I also have a df of signals with same keys and index as 'close'

```
signals
Out: 
                  SPY       F      AAPL
Date                                     
1995-01-03         0        0        0
1995-01-04         1        0        1
1995-01-05         1        1        1
1995-01-06         0        1        1
1995-01-09         0        0        0
1995-01-10         1        1        0
1995-01-11         1        1        0
1995-01-12         1        0        1
```

I want to fill the continous '1' series with the first value of the dataframe 'close' where signals switch from 0 to 1 such as

```
df
Out: 
                  SPY           F         AAPL
Date                                     
1995-01-03         0            0          0
1995-01-04         31.354707    0          1.279801
1995-01-05         31.354707    5.602394   1.279801
1995-01-06         0            5.602394   1.279801
1995-01-09         0            0          0
1995-01-10         31.450542    5.602394   0
1995-01-11         31.450542    5.602394   0
1995-01-12         31.450542    0          1.474819
```

really need help on this one. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
>>> starts = signals & (signals != signals.shift())
>>> (close.where(starts).ffill() * signals).fillna(0)
                  SPY         F      AAPL
Date                                     
1995-01-03   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
1995-01-04  31.354707  0.000000  1.279801
1995-01-05  31.354707  5.602394  1.279801
1995-01-06   0.000000  5.602394  1.279801
1995-01-09   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
1995-01-10  31.450542  5.602394  0.000000
1995-01-11  31.450542  5.602394  0.000000
1995-01-12  31.450542  0.000000  1.474819
```

Comment: Maybe I am plain stupid but starts = signals & (signals != signals.shift()) gives me and error :couldn't find matching opcode for 'and_bdb'.  if I do it like this starts =(signals != signals.shift()) it works perfectly fine! thanks alot!

Comment: This is an elegant answer.  Is the `!=` necessary?  Can't you just do `~signals.shift()`?

Comment: @StevenG just using `signals != signals.shift()` will include those lines where signals is 0 and the shift was 1.

Comment: thank you piR, will try to fix it. any idea why i get the error :couldn't find matching opcode for 'and_bdb' error?

Comment: @piRSquared: that's true, but I think you might be able to get away with it here because the `* signals` will zero out those unintended values.  This is just a guess, though, I haven't actually thought this through, in the middle of something else :-)

Comment: @piRSquared doing `code starts = signals * (signals != signals.shift())`  fix my problem I think. thanks for pointing that out